# Finding a function from a vector field

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

The vector field $F(x, y) = \left(\displaystyle\frac{x}{r^3}, \frac{y}{r^3}\right)$ appears in electrostatics, where $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ is the distance to the charge. Find a function $f(x, y)$ such that $F = ∇f$.

I took the integral of the first term with respect to $x$ and got $-(x^2 + y^2)^{-1/2} + c(y)$. Then I got $c'(y)$ as $0$. So is the answer$-(x^2 + y^2)^{-1/2}$?

Comment: Did you forget to say what the specific function $F$ is?

Comment: He has defined $F(x,y)$.

Comment: Differentiate your answer to check your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $c'(y) = 0$ then $c(y)$ is a constant that does not depend on $x$ or $y$. Therefore $$f(x,y) = -(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2} +k$$ where $k \in \Bbb R$.